# Are papers published as a result of winning a competition considered worth more / less than regularly published papers? (same journal)

Tags: publications, journals, career-path, paper-submission, early-career

I wonder the following. Say a reputable journal has an essay competition going on. The winner gets some money and is also published by that journal.

Would a publication like this weigh more than if the winner had just submitted that essay to the journal regularly? Or the other way around?

I think that winning a competition might be impressive. At the same time, suppose the essay competition question is very specific, which would result in not that many submissions. Would this change things? What else am I leaving out here?

I am in the Humanities, if that should make a difference (I know that many people on here are in the sciences). I would be very interested what you think. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience as reader and contributor to biomedical journals, if the journal is impactful and the prize is provided by an established entity, than a manuscript published in a given journal and awarded in some way is most always been given more recognition and dissemination than a standard manuscript.